# Stash filter entries by categories using match / against

Tags: categories, stash, filter

First of all I will collect all the website categories in a particular category group. Then, for each category group I will generate my Markup that will be fed to Jquery to generate navigational tabs. So far so good.

Then I will fetch (inside the category loop) the channel entries and I would like them to be actually filtered by category_id.

I get no output with this code:

> ```
> <!-- HERE I AM COLLECTING THE WEBSITE CATEGORIES -->
>
>     {exp:stash:set_list name="categories" scope="site" parse_tags="yes"}
>         {exp:channel:categories category_group="1"}
>         {stash:cat_name}{category_url_title}{/stash:cat_name}
>         {stash:cat_id}{category_id}{/stash:cat_id}
>         {/exp:channel:categories}
>     {/exp:stash:set_list}
>
> <!-- HERE I AM COLLECTING THE CHANNEL ENTRIES -->    
>     {exp:stash:set_list name="where" parse_tags="yes" process="end" parse_depth="3"}
>         {exp:channel:entries channel="dove_siamo" dynamic="no"}
>         {stash:item_entry_id}{entry_id}{/stash:item_entry_id}
>                     {categories}
>                     {stash:this_category}{category_id}{/stash:this_category}
>                     {/categories}
>             {exp:stash:set_list:nested name="address" context="{entry_id}" parse_tags="yes" }
>                     {address}
>                         {stash:via}{via}{/stash:via}
>                         {stash:cap}{cap}{/stash:cap}
>                         {stash:citta}{citta}{/stash:citta}
>                         {stash:ospedale}{ospedale}{/stash:ospedale}
>                         {stash:altro}{altro}{/stash:altro}
>                         {stash:centralino}{centralino}{/stash:centralino}
>                     {/address}
>             {/exp:stash:set_list:nested}
>         {/exp:channel:entries}
>     {/exp:stash:set_list}
> ```

> ```
>     {exp:stash:get_list name="categories"} 
>                <div id="{cat_name}">
>                     <section class="quick-info">
>                         <div class="vcard">
>                             <h4>Dove siamo</h4>
>                             <p>{cat_id}</p>
>                             {exp:stash:get_list:nested name="where" match="#^{this_category}$#" against="cat_id"}
>                             <p>{this_category}</p>
>                                 {exp:stash:get_list:nested_1 name="address" context="{item_entry_id}"}
>                                 <span class="adr">{via} {cap} - {citta}</span></br>
>                                 <span class="adr">{ospedale}</span></br>
>                                 <span class="adr">{altro}</span>
>                                 {/exp:stash:get_list:nested_1}
>                             {/exp:stash:get_list:nested}
>                         </div>
>                     </section>
>                 </div>
>     {/exp:stash:get_list}
> ```

Comment: Is anything output for the "categories" list at all (like the heading "Dove siam"), or is it only the interior nested list "where" that's not outputting anything?

Comment: With the above match / against I get nothing outputted by "Dove_siamo".
If I remove the parameters I get all the results.